# Problem while binding 100000 records from database to the data table in asp.netmvc using ADO.net

Tags: sql, angular, asp.net-web-api

In my table I'm having 1,50000 records, I have to display in front end table. In ASP.Net MVC using ADO.Net
getting 100000 records from SQL server database through Web API.I'm getting Memory out of range Exception while binding to the data table.

Comment: You will most probably run out of memory. Why don't you use `pagination`?

Comment: Retrieving 100000 of records in one query is not the ideal way to display the data since user will only view 10 - 100 records per page. If you are using datatables you might check this link https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side

Comment: there is no reason whatsoever to retrieve that much data in one go. pagination is the answer